# Change Status Bar to light without setting View Controller Based to NO

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I would like to set the status bar to white globally in my app, I have search around and the only way I found is to set into my project's info plist :

```
View controller-based status bar appearance YES
```

Then in my AppDelagte I do :

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle =   UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
```

Problem is when I change this value in the info plist it change my UI, I already set (now my view that are set to top layout guide @ 0 are under the status bar)

So guys, Is there a way for me to set the status bar in white all over the application without touching the View controller-based status bar appearance value ?

Thanks for all !